# Liquibase skip generated changeset

Tags: java, database, liquibase

We have a running project and we started using Liquibase. I generated ChangeSets from our existing database. I have integrated liquibase into our solution and now I need the initial ChangeSet to be skipped on systems with existing database, but I need to run it on newly installed systems. Is there any out-of-the-box solution for this scenario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run Liquibase once with the parameter `changelogSync` (instead of `update`), e.g.:

```
liquibase --changeLogFile=my_changelog.xml --defaultsFile=db.properties changeLogSync
```

That will mark all changesets from your changelog as being executed in the target database.

More details here: http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/existing_project.html